# Project root folder path

Tags: java, file-io, path

I have a class in a package com.mwerner.utils that needs the path for an `getResourceAsStream()` call

the file it is supposed to load is located in a subfolder of the project root i.e.:

/src/com/mwerner/utils/myfile.java   has to load

/res/file.xml

I tried stuff like

```
/res/file.xml
../res/file.xml
res/file.xml
```

What is the right one?

EDIT:

I am using Xstream to parse the XML into objects. The line of code in question is:

```
ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("res/file.xml"));
```

I get an `IOException` with `unknown source`

Comment: I dont't know how the code is executed, but try to add these lines 
`Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");`
`String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();`
`System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);`
This should print out the current folder

Comment: What did you try and what happened?

Comment: So the 'src' and 'res' directories are located in the same parent directory?

Comment: well the src folder is where eclipse stores the source code, the res folder is - like the src folder - in the root of the project, i.e. would be in the root of the JAR that i'd package for distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Eclipse puts the entire content of the `res` folder in the root folder of the `bin` folder. Therefore the path is just very simply `/file.xml`. I tried putting it into a subfolder of res called `xmls` and the path then is `/xmls/file.xml`

I also went to the source tab of the java build path and added the res folder.